# Change size of .pagination button?

Tags: html, css, button

so I'm using this guide to create a portfolio slider (https://github.com/lmgonzalves/momentum-slider)
But I dont like the size of the buttons which I want to make higher. It just seems like anything I do in the CSS file doesnt change anything. The buttons work and the CSS itself works, I just cant change the size of the button...

This is the link of the portfolio-carousel.css (https://github.com/lmgonzalves/momentum-slider/blob/master/css/portfolio-carousel.css)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css1/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css1/portfolio-carousel.css">
```

**then the buttons in HTML**

```
                    <main class="sliders-container">
                        <ul data-animate="fadeInUp" class="pagination">
                            <li data-animate="fadeInUp" class="pagination__item"><a 
    class="pagination__button"></a></li>
                            <li data-animate="fadeInUp" class="pagination__item"><a         
    class="pagination__button"></a></li>
                            <li data-animate="fadeInUp" class="pagination__item"><a 
    class="pagination__button"></a></li>
                            <li data-animate="fadeInUp" class="pagination__item"><a 
    class="pagination__button"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </main>
```

**Then i call the scripts**

```
<script src="../js1/momentum-slider.js"></script>
<script src="../js1/portfolio-carousel.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add increment padding property in your css. It will increate the size of the button

padding:10px;
if already have some padding add more px in padding if 10 then 15px so on...

Comment: Hi @flix I tried adding padding: 20px; and padding-top: 50px; etc, but nothing seemed to change the size of the buttons

Comment: add another property of css display: block;